# Show the independence of $\{f_n(x)=\frac1{n+x}\space|\space n \in\mathbb N\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

I'm currently trying to solve the following problem:

Show that the set of vectors $\{f_n(x)=\frac1{n+x}\space|\space n\in\mathbb N\}$ over the vector space of the functions from $\mathbb{R_{>0}}$ to $\mathbb R$ is linear independent.

I have managed to show it, but I used the geometric expansion and the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix, which is far to advanced for our current level. Is there a simpler way to approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $$\sum_1^N{a_n\over n+x}$$ is identically zero. Clearing fractions, $$p(x)=\sum a_nq_n(x)$$ is identically zero, where $q_n(x)=((1+x)\cdots(N+x))/(n+x)$. But if $a_n\ne0$, then $p(-n)\ne0$. Hence, $p(x)$ is identically zero if and only if $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you, but $x=-n$ is illegitimate because the $f_n:\mathbb{R_{>0}}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $p(x)$ is a polynomial. It makes sense to evaluate it at any real number. If its value at some real number is not zero, then it has only finitely many zeros, so it isn't identically zero on the positive real line. That's all you need.